# Odoo 11.0 How let res.partner about module tutorial being usable?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm pretty new about odoo, and starting from Build a Module with odoo 11.0.

All fine untill the tutorial point [Inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/backend.html#inheritance) that let me create a new Partener.py file that extend res.parter...

I followed and re-read the tutorial a lot of times and all it's same.
Why i get error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column res_users.notification_type does not exist

LINE 1: ... "share","res_users"."partner_id" as "partner_id","res_users...
```

This is partner.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import fields, models


class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    # Add a new column to the res.partner model, by default partners are not
    # instructors

    instructor = fields.Boolean("Instructor", default=False)

    session_ids = fields.Many2many('openacademy.session',
                                   string="Attended Sessions", readonly=True)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by generate a configuration file for odoo because the session that i start used the db of the last project so he don't have table inside db.

```
-s Path/odoorc_nameConfig -s --dev=xml,pdb,qweb
```

And add a dbfilter for see the proper db!

After that in the tutorial remind to add the depends 'sale' inside manifest!

```
'depends': ['base',
            'sale',
                ],
```

And now you can continue tutorial with Odoo 11.0 because they don't say that you need a depends with 'sale' for inherit class res.partner!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: "column res_partner.instructor does not exist"

I can solve this error by adding: 
Partner() at the end of the above code models/partner.py.

```
    from odoo import models, fields, api

    class Partner(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'res.partner'
        instructor = fields.Boolean("Instructor", default=False)

        session_ids = fields.Many2many('openacademy.session', 
        string="Attended Sessions", readonly=True)

    Partner()
```

Another way is to add fields through SQL.

```
    sudo -u postgres psql
    \c yourdatabase
    ALTER TABLE res_partner ADD COLUMN instructor boolean default False;
```

restart and ready.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by  doing immediate upgrade of custom module after restarting  server.( Steps : 1 - comment  import partner instruction , 2- Launch the server ,  3- go to apps and select your custom app , 4- uncomment import partner and launch the server 5- Go to your apps and do the upgrade directly without refreshing the page )

This should be the case when you add any new fields to the res_company, res_partner, res_users tables. 
See this link for more details : 
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/hi-everyone-here-i-need-the-solution-in-this-error-programmingerror-column-res-partner-instructor-does-not-exist-i-was-trying-to-inherit-res-partner-in-my-custom-module-129222